# Bedrock WordPress retro-porting to standard WP installation: is this allowed?

Tags: directory, development-strategy

I am dealing with something never seen before: a WordPress website where there is not standard directories, and wp-content was moved in /app, all files was moved elsewhere and all seems to work properly, backend/frontend side. It should be done using BedRock, as I see.

Please take a look at here:

```
- index.php
- app/
--- plugins/
--- uploads/
- wp/
--- wp-admin/
--- wp-snapshots/
--- wp-config.php
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihbiq.jpg

Could be this a standard re-packaging structure (i.e using Composer or similar)? Or just something does not deserve to be discussed here (in this case, sorry for my ignorance)? Thanks in advance

My question in detail:
can I pass to standard WP copything theme/plugins directories and mantaining this working?

Comment: It's possible to change the directory structure like this by defining some contents in wp-config.php. What's your question?

Comment: edited better now